# How to return a sequence of numbers from MySQL FUNCTION?

Tags: mysql, database, function, variables, stored-procedures

For example, if I write the query into the `Stored Procedure` it gives a sequence of numbers like this normally:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedureA()
    BEGIN
        SET @items := 0;
        SELECT @items := @items + 1 AS `count`, t.* FROM notepad t;
    END //

 count | item |
-------+------+
   1   |  A   |
   2   |  B   |
   3   |  C   |
```

But when I re-write this query on `FUNCTION` it won't give the sequence anymore:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNumberOfItems()
    RETURNS INT
    BEGIN
        SET @items := 0;
        RETURN(SELECT @items := @items + 1 AS `count`);
    END //

 count | item |
-------+------+
   1   |  A   |
   1   |  B   |
   1   |  C   |
```

Using parentheses on `RETURN` keyword also won't work in this case:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNumberOfItems()
    RETURNS INT
    RETURN(
        SET @items := 0;
        SELECT @items := @items + 1 AS `count`
    ) //
```

Are there any ways to return the sequence of numbers from `FUNCTION` like `PROCEDURE` does?

Comment: MySQL functions are only intended to return one value.

Comment: @zealous It doesn't work for me. It still returns only 1, not the sequence of numbers.

Comment: @Nick Then are there no ways to create a custom function like `ROW_NUMBER()`?  My goal is to create the function that counts every items in a row.

Comment: You could try writing something which used variables to maintain state e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=60329f0fcffbe40c5de47006963ac44a but I wouldn't guarantee that it would work...

Comment: @Nick I just tested it with that and it works what I expected. This helps me a lot. Thank you so much.

Comment: Cool - I'm glad it's useful. As I said though, I can't guarantee it would work in all situations so I won't post as an answer.

Comment: @Nick Just 1 more quick question. Are there any websites that can be able to check the syntax of built-in `FUNCTIONS` of MySQL? (Like `COUNT()`, `ROW_NUMBER()`, `OVER()` etc.) I want to see them for learning more faster and easier.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by check the syntax? there's the reference manual at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ or https://mysqltutorial.org or you can just use sites like https://dbfiddle.uk to test code

Comment: @Nick Sorry I was a bit unclear. What I want is, to see the whole structure (not the syntax) of every each built-in FUNCTIONS to understand how it made.

Comment: For that you'd have to look at the code base...

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (id CHAR(1)) 
> SELECT 'A' id UNION SELECT 'B' UNION SELECT 'C';
> SELECT * FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> | id |
> | :- |
> | A  |
> | B  |
> | C  |
> ```

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION getNumberOfItems()
>     RETURNS INT
>     RETURN ( @items := COALESCE(@items, 0) + 1 );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT id, getNumberOfItems() FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | getNumberOfItems()
> :- | -----------------:
> A  |                  1
> B  |                  2
> C  |                  3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9010567ded5e17264c46182a7194a15d)*